# Assign string to column of char array

Tags: c++, string, multidimensional-array, char

I am trying to assign a string like "hello" to a column of a multidimensional char array in C++.When it's finished for example the first column of the 2D array should become "hello" from top to bottom.

I am looking for a simple solution without using a for loop for example using strcpy().Is it possible?

Comment: Please include the code for what you have tried, what results you are getting and what results you are expecting.

Comment: Your biggest issue will be that C++ is row-major order and the strcpy function will operate on a row.

Comment: It seems it is for example a[10][10]. a[0] is a pointer that can be sent to strcpy.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no standard library function to do this. What you want is a copy with a write-*stride* that is not provided in the library. But it's absolutely trivial to do with a very short `for` loop. Why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: @yzt I reckon he _really_ doesn't want to use multi-dimensional arrays, because writing loops for them can be tricky. My answer shows how a modicum of C++11 can reduce this problem quite a bit. (_I still recommend against multi-dimensional arrays, but that's irrelevant)

Comment: I assume a `while()` loop is also out of the question (just curious if the instructor said "no for-loops" or just "no loops").

Comment: What I was looking for is assigning a string to a column of array just like: strcpy(ARRAY[0]="hello")

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advice against raw multi-dimensional arrays in C++ - they're error prone and inflexible. Consider Boost MultiArray.

That said, you could always "hide" the complexity by writing a helper function. Here's a fairly generic version that works with 2-dimensional arrays of any size/element type:

```
template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
   void setColumn(T(&arr)[N][M], size_t col, std::string const& val)
{
    assert(col>=0 && col <M);

    for (auto& row : arr)
        row[col] = val;
}
```

Note how it

- takes the array by reference, so template argument deduction can be used to "sense" the dimension bounds (N, M)
- it asserts that the column index is actually valid (bonus feature)
- it uses range-based `for`, which is actually pretty concise, and certainly helps hide all the ***clutter*** that using 2-dim arrays in C++ would otherwise expose you to.

### How to use it?

```
std::string arr[][7] = {
    { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" },
    { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" },
    { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" },
    { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" },
    { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" },
    { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" },
};

// straightforward:
setColumn(arr, 0, "hello");
```

Or, if you don't like having to "say" which array, use a lambda:

```
// to make it even more concise
auto setColumn = [&](int c, std::string const& val) mutable { ::setColumn(arr, c, val); };

setColumn(3, "world");
```

A live demonstration is ***[Here on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=40acf162e32c267fdd7e543d4d1f1863-542192d2d8aca3c820c7acc656fa0c68)*** and it prints

```
hello;1;2;world;4;5;6;
hello;1;2;world;4;5;6;
hello;1;2;world;4;5;6;
hello;1;2;world;4;5;6;
hello;1;2;world;4;5;6;
hello;1;2;world;4;5;6;
```

using the simple code

```
// dump it for demo purposes
for (auto& row : arr)
{
    std::copy(begin(row), end(row), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ";"));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Very nice, but I *think* OP wants a given column to contain `"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"` and not `"hello"` six times.

Comment: @juanchopanza "first column of the 2D array should become "hello" from top to bottom" - i'm not entirely sure what makes you conclude your interpretation is more likely :| I agree both are _possible_

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do this using the standard library functions.

However it is an easy thing to accomplish with a simple loop:

```
std::size_t col = 0;
std::string s{"hello"};
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != s.size(); ++i) {
    arr[i][col] = s[i];
}
```

Note, this doesn't do bounds checking if `s.size()` is greater than the row dimension of `arr`.

**Live example:** http://ideone.com/K63uDQ

Answer (score 0):

Using strcpy():

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
        const int rows = 10; 
        const int cols = 10; 
        const int wordlen = 255;

        char a[rows][cols][wordlen];
        for (int ix = 0; ix < rows ; ++ix)
            strcpy(a[ix][0] , "hello");
        for (int ix = 0; ix < rows ; ++ix)
            cout << a[ix][0] << endl;
}
```

Using for_each() function:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string* val(string *s) 
{
    s[0] = "hello";
    return s;
}

int main()
{    
        const int rows = 8;
        const int cols = 8;

        string a[rows][cols];
        for (int ix = 0; ix < rows; ++ix)
            for (int jx = 0; jx < cols; ++jx)
                a[ix][jx] = "something";
        for_each(a,a+rows,val);
        for (int ix = 0; ix < rows; ++ix)
            for (int jx = 0; jx < cols; ++jx)
                cout << "a[" << ix << "][" << jx << "] = " << a[ix][jx] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but still what I was looking for was a more simple solution.Using addresses and pointers without using for loops.But still thanks